# Install serverless framework to execute nodejs application in aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

While testing the lambda function in api gateway i get below error message.
Let me give some some background here that what I'm doing.

I've created a stack which is creating apigateway, lambda and dynamo db.
The project has serverless.yml consisting of below configurations

I'm new to this setup and what I understand is that I'll have to install serverless framework (may with "sudo npm -i -g serverless") on lambda. Could you help me understanding where and how can I get this done OR is it something which Developers has to take care of?

Please let me know if you any other details.

**serverless.yml**

```
service: ps-hbo-api
plugins: ${file(./serverless-${self:provider.stage}.yml):plugins}
custom: ${file(./serverless-${self:provider.stage}.yml):custom}
vfg: ${file(./serverless-${self:provider.stage}.yml):vfg}
logs: ${file(./serverless-${self:provider.stage}.yml):logs}
```

**serverless-prod.yml**

```
plugins:
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
#Testing otherwise has to be removed  
  - serverless-http
```

**index.js**

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

**Error message**

```
    {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'serverless-http'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","trace":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'serverless-http'","Require stack:","- /var/task/index.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js [TRUNCATED]
Fri May 14 07:53:59 UTC 2021 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Error: Cannot find module 'serverless-http'
        Require stack:
        - /var/task/index.js
        - /var/runtime/UserFunction.js
        - /var/runtime/index.js. Lambda request id: 2fe67c72-8d94-4011-b274-c7c91f10cdcf
        Fri May 14 07:53:59 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Comment: Did you run an install command to install the serverless-http plugin or did you just copy and paste the serverless-http line into your serverless.yml? Typically you need to use `serverless plugin install --name serverless-http` which adds the plugin for you entirely or at least `npm i --save serverless-http` and then add the -plugin into your serverless.yml manually

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In your local machine when you are deploying the serverless project?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after you are deploying your lambda functions, it was not able to find the `serverless-http` npm dependency. Hence, I would recommend adding the `serverless-plugin-include-dependencies` plugin in your `serverless-prod.yml` so that it downloads and install the necessary dependencies while deploying your project.

After adding the plugin, here's how it should look like.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
```

You can check the details of the dependency plugin [here from the serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies).

Comment: Thank you very much @raez murshed.  I tried adding the plugin but we still have the same error message. I think we get to install serverless framework first. I went through many articles but didn't get much to understand how and where should I install these modules. Basically how does it look in stack cloud formation template. Could you help me with sample example?

Comment: You need to install the serverless along with those serverless plugins in the machine where you are running `serverless deploy -s prod`

Comment: yeah. We came up with alternative approach like, serverless-prod.yml and serverless-dev.yml are basically used to define their environment respective variables. So, I've defined all these variables as environment variables in lambda function definition in my Application stack itself. It started working for us then. We have given away with serverless.